# Am hitting this issue: TriggertoCreateContactformCase at line 13, column 1: Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: apex, trigger

Someone please help me. I have the ff apex trigger code and its hitting this issue:

*"TriggertoCreateContactformCase at line 13, column 1: Too many query rows: 50001"*

**ApexTriggerCode:**

```
trigger TriggertoCreateContactformCase on Case (before insert) {
    List<String> UseremailAddresses = new List<String>();
    //First exclude any cases where the contact is set
    for (Case c:Trigger.new) {
        if (c.ContactId==null &&
            c.SuppliedEmail!=''|| c.SuppliedEmail==null)
        {
            UseremailAddresses.add(c.SuppliedEmail);
        }
    }

    //Now we have a nice list of all the email addresses.  Let's query on it and see how many contacts already exist.
    List<Contact> listofallContacts = [Select Id,Email From Contact Where Email in:UseremailAddresses];
    Set<String> ExstingEmails = new Set<String>();
    for (Contact c:listofallContacts) {
        ExstingEmails.add(c.Email);
    }

    Map<String,Contact> emailToContactMap = new Map<String,Contact>();
    List<Case> casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();

    for (Case c:Trigger.new) {
        if (c.ContactId==null &&
            c.SuppliedName!=null &&
            c.SuppliedEmail!=null &&
            c.SuppliedName!='' &&
           !c.SuppliedName.contains('@') &&
            c.SuppliedEmail!='' &&
           !ExstingEmails.contains(c.SuppliedEmail))
        {
            //The case was created with a null contact
            String[] Emailheader = c.SuppliedName.split(' ',2);
            String email = c.suppliedEmail;
            String companyName = email.substringBetween('@', '.com');
            System.debug('------------> CompanyName ' + companyName);

            if (Emailheader.size() == 2)
            {
                Contact conts = new Contact(FirstName=Emailheader[0],
                                            LastName=Emailheader[1],
                                            Email=c.SuppliedEmail,  PLDT_Enterprise_Email__c = c.SuppliedEmail,
                                            PLDT_Home_Email__c = c.SuppliedEmail,   Smart_Email__c = c.SuppliedEmail,
                                            PLDT_Home__c = false, PLDT_Enterprise__c = false, Smart__c = false

                                            );
                emailToContactMap.put(c.SuppliedEmail,conts);
                casesToUpdate.add(c);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Contact> newContacts = emailToContactMap.values();
    System.debug('------------> Contacts ' + newContacts);
    insert newContacts;

    for (Case c:casesToUpdate) {
        Contact newContact = emailToContactMap.get(c.SuppliedEmail);

        c.ContactId = newContact.Id;
    }
}
```

How to optimize. Please help me.

Comment: First thing that i would do is to use set and not a list for storing those email addresses. That way you would have only unique ones.

Comment: And you're trying to add null emails. You have probably mistake in your condition c.Suppliedemail == null

Answer (score 4):

As user1974566 has commented, it may be that this query has `null` in the `UseremailAddresses` list:

```
[Select Id,Email From Contact Where Email in:UseremailAddresses];
```

which instead of limiting the number of Contact records to the *small* number of specific email addresses from the Cases, ends up also querying *all* Contact records that don't have an email address. As soon as the volume of Contact records in your org that don't have an email address grows to > 50,000 this error starts appearing.

A quick way to check is to change that query to:

```
[Select Id,Email From Contact Where Email in:UseremailAddresses and Email != null];
```

If this is the problem, you should fix it in your earlier logic.

Also using `String.isNotBlank` that covers both `null` and `''` will make your code a little clearer and a little more likely to work:

```
Set<String> UseremailAddresses = new Set<String>();
for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
    if (c.ContactId == null && String.isNotBlank(c.SuppliedEmail)) {
        UseremailAddresses.add(c.SuppliedEmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback. Will check with our team and follow the recommendation.